# i want to run and app script in google docs to fetch data from adobe target, what are the steps to do that

Tags: google-apps-script, adobe

i have got the App script code(from another team member), but while running it getting the below error.

Exception: Request failed for https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"error_description":"JWT token is incorrectly formatted, and can not be decoded.","error":"invalid_token"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

If i need to do it from scratch, what are the steps involved to do it

how can i fetch the details of adobe target activity to update in google docs

Comment: If you share the code you attempted to use, we may be able to assist. Just based on the error, it may be a simple issue with your token. You may also find an answer [over here](https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-campaign-standard/quot-jwt-token-is-incorrectly-formatted-quot-error-when-trying/m-p/180809).